# Unix shell scripting

Tags: shell, unix

I have write shell script to find the particular filename in the directory and create list file to copy the filenames automatically in that list file. But my script is not working list file is not created automatically. I don't know the issue in my script.

```
Scripts='/app/file'
SrcFiles='/app/file/Mainfiles'
cd "$SrcFiles"
touch SOURCE.LIST
chmod 777 SOURCE.LIST
cd "$Scripts"
cd "$SrcFiles"
for f in *.csv
do
   cp -v "$f" /app/file/Mainfiles/SOURCE.LIST/"${f%.csv}"
done
```

Comment: `cp -v "$f" /app/file/Mainfiles/SOURCE.LIST/"${f}.csv"`

Answer (score 0):

Please try below

```
search_dir="/app/file/Mainfiles"
for entry in "$search_dir"/*
do echo "$(basename $entry)" >> "/app/file/Mainfiles/SOURCE.LIST"
done
```